# HQL: Find one weekdays value or the one before

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

Scenario:
I got a database with a table for funds and one for quotes (daily share price) and I need to calculate the weekly performance (Sunday's value - last Sunday's value) **of every fund in every week**. To do that I need to get the price of the fund from every Sunday in the database. The issue is that on some Sundays there is no value and so I need to take the closest possible value before Sunday.

My current "solution" (which very very slow):

```
        List<Double> result = new ArrayList<>();

        LocalDate date = startDate;
        date = date.with(previous(SUNDAY));

        LocalDate end = LocalDate.now();
        end = end.with(next(SUNDAY));

        while (date.isBefore(end))
        {
            date = date.with(next(SUNDAY));
            result.add(
                    session.createQuery("select price from QuotesEntity where fundId = :a and date < :b Order By date desc", Double.class)
                    .setParameter("a", fundId)
                    .setParameter("b", Date.valueOf(date))
                    .setMaxResults(1)
                    .getSingleResult());
        }

        return result;
```

Problem with current code:
The reason it is so slow is that I need to request at least 150+ queries per fund and in production, I will have around 2 million funds in my database, instead of the 300 I got for testing. In the best case, I would only need 1 query to get all Sunday's values (or the one before) of 1 fund.

I have already tried indexing the date column and the fundId column, which improved it a bit, but it needs a ton of disk space on my server.

Comment: Have you find out the reason why is it very slow? Does the MySQL query makes it slow? How much row of data is in the table? Are the related columns being indexed? I assume there are a lot of data in the table and the condition `and date < :b` are getting everything before the date selected instead of a week of data worth..

Comment: True, however I need some query like this if there is no quote for a Sunday and I should pick the one before. If a fund doesn't have a quote in our database for let's say 2 months, I need to get the last entry which is 2 months back, so setting a limit for going back could potentially mess with my math (where I compare 2 funds with each other and both need the same amount of values) later on.

Comment: What if you just extract every data correspond to the day you need first? Then perform the query over it. So instead of `and date < :b`, how about something like `DAYNAME(date)='Sunday'`. I'm not certain how quick the query would be but at least you could reduce the query returning 7/7 to 1/7. In any way, you could give some illustration on how much the data currently in the table, 1,000 rows? 10,000 rows? or more?